# ItextSharp generates pdf file of 0 bytes in PC build. Works in editor

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, itext

I am using iTextSharp.dll to generate a pdf in a PC build. Version: 2018.4.9f - OS 10 - Build:PC - C# - Visual Studio 2017 community

The pdf is being generated in the editor as it should with the text I put in the script but after building for PC it generated a pdf with 0 Bytes. When it is opened it pops a dialog box saying file type not recognized or Damaged pdf. How does it achieve the same result in PC build? What am I missing?

In my scene, I have a camera with a c# script on it. Script has a single method which is called when a UI button is pressed. Here is the code:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System;

public class Panel : MonoBehaviour
{
     WaitForEndOfFrame frameEnd = new WaitForEndOfFrame();

     public void EnglishPdf()
     {
         FileStream fs = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)+ "\\Test.pdf", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
         Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4);
         PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);
         doc.Open();

         //Page0
         doc.NewPage();
         // PdfPTable page0 = new PdfPTable(2);
         Paragraph title = new Paragraph("Test PDF");
         title.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

         Chunk nameChunk = new Chunk("Name: "  + "\r\n");
         Chunk bday = new Chunk("Date of Birth: "  );
         doc.Add(title);
         // doc.Add(page0);
         doc.Add(nameChunk);
         doc.Add(bday);

         doc.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: 0 bytes means that itext didn't even start writing to the file, otherwise there would be a few bytes pdf header. I would assume that the file stream creation `FileStream fs = ...` works but nothing thereafter. Have you checked for errors?

Comment: There are no errors in .net or unity editor, there aren't any build or compile errors either.

Comment: Then either the code compiled into the PC build is not the code you show (probably an earlier build without the itext code, merely with the `FileStream` initialization?), or some other program intervenes, or you have a miracle.

Comment: There are no other programs. Only a script and a single button that calls the above function.

Comment: Have you tried some standard debugging methods? Like adding a `Console` write on every other line and checking whether any or all of those writes hey written?

Comment: I am trying to debug using visual studio debugger

Comment: Update: I created a development build with the script logging enabled and it shows up error: platform not supported exception. This platform is not supported. Does that means I have to find another plugin to create a pdf? Or is there a workaround?

Comment: You might want to make that the focus of your question - what exactly are the requirements in the Unity context. Based on that you may have to choose some different libraries among your dependencies.

Comment: Which *exact* version of iText are you using? You mention "iTextSharp", which is the  old name of iText for .NET, and is probably in the version range 4.x.x-5.x.x. But I really need to know the exact version. The most recent version of iText for .NET is 7.1.9 and was released one month ago. You seem to be developing for Unity. The old version of iText may just not be compatible with Unity, I don't know. Please try with the most recent version of iText.

Comment: Thanks, Amedee... I was thinking the same thing. My itextsharp version is 5.x. I am going to try with latest iText.

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading to itext7. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, it was version issue. I fixed it by upgrading to itext7